# Error while iterating

Tags: c++

This is my implementation for a minor of a 3x3 matrix.
The problem is that for some weird reason `j` doesn't reach 2, any idea why this happens?

```
//return the minor of a 3x3 matrix
int matrix::minor(int element) const {
    std::vector <int> list;
    if (rows == columns) {
        int result = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns && j != element; j++) {
                std::cout << "Adding element " << array[i][j] << std::endl;
                list.push_back(array[i][j]);
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        a = list[0] * list[3];
        b = list[1] * list[2];
        result = a - b;
        return result;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not a square matrix" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm not using the first row because it's where the pivots are, `element` is the pivot position in the first row.

Comment: `j != element` condition may be false, making your program to jump out of the inner `for` loop before `j` reaching 2.

Comment: I though it will iterate to the next number, not to exit the entire `for` how can i fix that?

Comment: @RenatoA. If that were true, how would you ever exit the `for` loop?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz in other languajes the iterator have priority, I was using them and when tried c++ again I forgot that cpp does exactly what you write, not even think about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic breaks the loop instead of ignoring that iteration of `j` when `j` is  equal to `element`.

Assuming the value of `element` can be 0, 1, or 2, your logic needs to be:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { // Note the change to the initial value of i
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if ( j != element )
            {
               std::cout << "Adding element " << array[i][j] << std::endl;
               list.push_back(array[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

In a comment, you said:

> nope the value of i must be 1 because I'm jumping the first row

That's fair. However, I would change `minor` to not assume `1`. Provide both the row and column indices to compute the rank.

```
int matrix::minor(int irank, int jrank) const
{
   std::vector <int> list;
   if (rows == columns)
   {
      int result = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      {
         if ( i != irank )
         {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
               if ( j != jrank )
               {
                  std::cout << "Adding element " << array[i][j] << std::endl;
                  list.push_back(array[i][j]);
               }
            }
         }
      }

      std::cout << std::endl;
      a = list[0] * list[3];
      b = list[1] * list[2];
      result = a - b;
      return result;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "Not a square matrix" << std::endl;
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe that sh*ty `for` breaks just for nothing, I spent too much time in high level programming languages now I'm struggling again with c++ thanks

Comment: nope the value of i must be 1 because I'm jumping the first row